# Is there any other way to handle Chrome's Print Preview window when automating with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webautomation, print-preview

I am trying to automate the printing of a document obtained from a website. 
When I click the Print button on the web page, Chrome's print-preview appears and I have to choose from the drop-box('Save as PDF' or 'Print').

I am using Selenium with Python and didn't find any way to access that Print-Preview window.

**Is there any other way that this can be done?**

I don't have code to show you right now. It takes in details that are confidential for the company.

Comment: Do you want to select from the list and hit on the save/print, or just select?

Comment: I need to select from the list